# Amazon Athena : How to store results after querying with skipping column headers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I ran a simple query using Athena dashboard on data of format csv.The result was a csv with column headers.
When storing the results,Athena stores with the column headers in s3.How can i skip storing header column names,as i have to make new table from the results and it is repetitive

Answer (score 2):

Try "skip.header.line.count"="1", This feature has been available on AWS Athena since 2018-01-19, here's a sample:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName (
  `field1` string,
  `field2` string,
  `field3` string 
)
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'separatorChar' = ',',
   'quoteChar' = '\"',
   'escapeChar' = '\\'
   )
LOCATION 's3://fileLocation/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')
```

You can refer to this question:
[Aws Athena - Create external table skipping first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452010/aws-athena-create-external-table-skipping-first-row)

Answer (score 1):

From [an Eric Hammond post on AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=245579):

```
...
  WHERE
    date NOT LIKE '#%'
...
```

I found this works! The steps I took:

- Run an Athena query, with the output going to Amazon S3
- Created a new table pointing to this output based on [How do I use the results of my Amazon Athena query in another query?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-query-results/), changing the path to the correct S3 location
- Ran a query on the new table with the above `WHERE <datefield> NOT LIKE '#%'`

However, subsequent queries store even more data in that S3 directory, so it confuses any subsequent executions.

Comment: I refered [Eric Hammond post on AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=245579).In that case, the file starts with '#%',so above query applies.In my case, i think i have to say where <datatype> NOT LIKE '<column name/file start identifier' is a work around.Are there any workaround without using where clause?

Comment: My file did NOT start with `#%` either, but it worked for me from an Athena output file. I suspect it is because a Date field isn't loaded from a header text string, making it NULL and the `NOT LIKE` filters based upon that. Try it, it will actually work for you!

Comment: you are right,it worked!,changed it to `WHERE <datatype> NOT LIKE '<header-column-name>'` as i do not have datetime field in my results,so kept the relevant datatype(string) in my case.

Comment: but sadly my result has a column header again,so it again becomes the same thing, did u see the column headers in,after u ran query on new table with `WHERE <datefield> NOT LIKE '#%'`,and may u try creating a table with that,because for me the column header still persists in the output no matter what

Comment: Mmm. Strangely, I am unable to repeat my prior success. Now I can't query the result table at all! Sorry, can't help any further.