# Aws Athena - Create external table skipping first row

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm trying to create an external table on csv files with Aws Athena with the code below but the line `TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1")` doesn't work: it doesn't skip the first line (header) of the csv file.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mytable
(
  colA string,
  colB int
  )

 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'separatorChar' = ',',
   'quoteChar' = '\"',
   'escapeChar' = '\\'
   )
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://mybucket/mylocation/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "skip.header.line.count"="1")
```

Any advise?

Comment: exist a way to add header to TEXTFILE  in create table as cte ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Just tried the `"skip.header.line.count"="1"` and seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work anymore. Not sure when this will be really fixed.

Comment: TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')  .. worked fine for me

Comment: it starts to work since 2018-01-19. see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/release-note-2018-01-19.html

Answer (score 7):

On the AWS Console you can specify it as Serde parameters key-value keypair

[image: skip header in athena table]

While if you apply your infrastructure as code with terraform you can use **ser_de_info** parameter - **"skip.header.line.count" = 1**. Example bellow

```
resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "banana_datalake_table" {
  name          = "mapping"
  database_name = "banana_datalake"
  table_type    = "EXTERNAL_TABLE"
    owner = "owner"
    storage_descriptor {
        location        = "s3://banana_bucket/"
        input_format    = "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat"
        output_format   = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat"
        compressed  = "false"
        number_of_buckets = -1    
        ser_de_info {
            name    = "SerDeCsv"
            serialization_library = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe"
            parameters {
                "field.delim" = ","
                "skip.header.line.count" = 1    # Skip file headers
            }
        }
        columns {
            name    = "column_1"
            type    = "string"
        }
        columns {
            name    = "column_2"
            type    = "string"
        }
        columns {
            name    = "column_3"
            type    = "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a feature that has not yet been implemented. See Abhishek@AWS' response [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=245579):

> "We are working on it and will report back as soon as we have an
>   outcome. Sorry for this again. This ended up taking longer than what
>   we anticipated."

My workaround has been to preprocess the data before creating the table:

1. download the csv file from S3
2. strip the header using bash `sed -e 1d -e 's/\"//g' file.csv > file-2.csv`
3. upload the results to its own folder on S3
4. create the table

Comment: This feature has been available on AWS Athena since 2018-01-19. see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/release-note-2018-01-19.html
> Support for ignoring headers. You can use the skip.header.line.count property when defining tables, to allow Athena to ignore headers.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct and should be unaccepted as the correct one. skip.header.line.count does work.

Answer (score 5):

I recently tried:

```
TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')
```

And it works fine now. This issue arose when I had the column header as a string (timestamp) and the records where actual timestamps. My queries would bomb as it would scan the table and find a string instead of `timestamp`.

Something like this:

> ts
>   2015-06-14 14:45:19.537
>   2015-06-14 14:50:20.546

Answer (score 1):

When this question was asked there was no support for skipping headers, and when it [was later introduced](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/release-note-2018-01-19.html) it was only for the [OpenCSVSerDe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html), not for [LazySimpleSerDe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/lazy-simple-serde.html), which is what you get when you specify `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS …`. I think this is what has caused some confusion about whether or not it works in the answers to this question.