# AWS Athena Import CSV file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have this data stored in S3 as .csv (but it can be any other file format which is the best suitable for my requirement):

```
"41.9100687,-87.8805614","41.9802511,-87.8803253","41.9806802,-87.8792417","41.9810128,-87.8785121","41.9200687,-87.8805614","41.9802511,-87.8803253","41.9806802,-87.8792417",
"41.9100687,-87.8805614","41.9802511,-87.8803253","41.9806802,-87.8792417","41.9810128,-87.8785121","41.9200687,-87.8805614","41.9802511,-87.8803253","41.9806802,-87.8792417",
"41.9100687,-87.8805614","41.9802511,-87.8803253","41.9806802,-87.8792417","41.9810128,-87.8785121","41.9200687,-87.8805614","41.9802511,-87.8803253","41.9806802,-87.8792417",
"41.9100687,-87.8805614","41.9802511,-87.8803253","41.9806802,-87.8792417","41.9810128,-87.8785121","41.9200687,-87.8805614","41.9802511,-87.8803253","41.9806802,-87.8792417",
```

and I would like to have one coordinate per column:

Like this:

Coordinates:

```
1.  41.9100687,-87.8805614

2.  41.9802511,-87.8803253

3.  41.9806802,-87.8792417
```

After importing S3 I choose CSV as data type... And then I add string column.

[image]

But instead I get some weird table output. Beside this I tried to import this as plain txt file with comma delimiter.. I get same weird output.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

This `test` column screenshot is query from another but identical example. There should be `gps_coordinates`

Comment: Is the file in a folder on its own (with no other files)? Did your LOCATION statement point to the folder or the file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created a text file using your sample data (`gps.txt`)
- Uploaded it to an Amazon S3 bucket **in its own folder** (with no other files in that folder)
- Created a table in Amazon Athena

  - Specified the location as the **folder name** (`s3://my-bucket/gps/`)
  - Specified **7 columns** (since there are 7 string values in your sample file)

However, since the data has commas within each pair of numbers, I **changed the SerDe** to [OpenCSVSerDe for Processing CSV - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html):

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.gps (
  `c1` string,
  `c2` string,
  `c3` string,
  `c4` string,
  `c5` string,
  `c6` string,
  `c7` string 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = ",", "escapeChar" = "\\") 

LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/gps/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

I was then able to **successfully query** the table. A sample column value is: `41.9100687,-87.8805614`

Comment: Is there a way to ignore the first row which is header column

Comment: @kumar [Aws Athena - Create external table skipping first row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47280738/174777)

Comment: @kumar TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1")