# How get data from s3 bucket to aws athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm unable to get the CSV file data from the s3 bucket into AWS Athena.

I'm getting a schema for the file, not the data

Error message as no records returned.

Comment: Do you have any code to reproduce? Could you please provide the complete error log?

Comment: If you could provide sample CSV file data and Athena table structure here, you will get better response..

Comment: @Pooja : Please add the sample code of your create external table command. And sample csv data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Athena directly reads data from Amazon S3.

You must first use `CREATE TABLE` to define the format and location of the data. You can then query against the table.

Comment: Thanks, John for the response, I had created the table which is successful, but couldn't fetch the data from s3?

Comment: In that case, either the table definition is incorrect or is pointing to the wrong location, or the data in S3 is not accessible to you. Please edit your Question to show your `CREATE TABLE` statement and provide a (short) sample of the data you are trying to query. That way, we can attempt to reproduce your situation. Without this information, we are unable to offer you any suggestions.

Comment: Hello John, I have solved the problem, I did a mistake where I kept all my CSV files in a bucket directly so that it unable to identify which one, later on, I made a folder and kept all my CSV files into then I was able to fetch the data. But one of my CSV file includes headers, data is fetched with headers. can't we fetch the data without headers?

Comment: Yes, but it depends how you are defining the table. See: [Aws Athena - Create external table skipping first row - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452010/aws-athena-create-external-table-skipping-first-row)

Comment: Is there any link that helps me how to fetch data from glue data catalog?

Comment: @PoojaPediredla I'm not sure what you mean by that. Do you mean as a query? (Feel free to ask another Question with the details/example.)

Comment: Hi John, I have a scenario where I transfer 15GB of data into s3 and from s3 transfer to snowflake using either snow pipe or SAP data services on a daily bases. How it cost me? I've checked in the simple monthly calculator, but I got confused that the data transfer option is to apply for s3 standard storage or not?

Comment: Data Transfer applies to data being transferred from AWS to the Internet, or between AWS regions. This applies to any service (eg S3 files, EC2 web pages, etc). It is _not_ related to storage types. It applies to the volume of data sent to the Internet.